# curl (7) error when trying to install Homebrew on mac

Tags: php, macos, curl, ffmpeg, homebrew

Wanted to install Homebrew on my mac (on version 10.11.6) and put this into terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

The thing i get is the following:

```
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Now, I don't have any knowledge about terminal and curl and proxy and all this stuff, but I really need Homebrew (actually I need ffmpeg but apparently homebrew is necessary for ffmpeg)... I remember having ffmpeg already installed half a year ago, but somehow I got it deleted. Now, I have a backup of that time, so can I just recover it - just homebrew and ffmpeg without recovering the whole backup? Or is there a way just to install homebrew again?

Thanks for helping!

-Peleadora

Answer (score 2):

You are using the outdated link.

You should use this instead (excerpt from [brew.sh](http://brew.sh/))

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

EDIT:
If your curl keep not working, you can just download `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install` via any other means.
Assuming the name of the downloaded file is `install`, you can run it with ruby by this.

```
/usr/bin/ruby install
```

Comment: Tried this one, too, still get the same error :/
Actually, I tried a lot of different links I found while my search, but nothing was working...

Comment: Well, are you accessible to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install` via any tools other than curl (e.g. your web browser)?

Comment: If you are accessible, download the file manually and just run the file with ruby will let you install Homebrew.

Comment: Yeah, I get this file "install" when opening the link via the web browser, but when i put this /usr/bin/ruby install into the terminal it says:

/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- install (LoadError)

Comment: If you don't have Xcode then install it. If you don't have CLT (or just don't have a idea what CLT is) then run `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Maybe you should make a separate question about the missing ruby. I'm sorry I can't help you.